# Using Selenium + Python 3.8 and having trouble clicking a link, wondering how to handle onclick?

Tags: python, selenium, onclick

I'm using python + selenium to try and automate a few things. I've had success using it before, but I am stuck on this issue. Every time I try and click on this link I get a "NoSuchElementException". Here is the html from the portion of the webpage:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:menu_display_document(event,this,6,12);" target="_self">Knowledge Base.html</a>
```

Some things I have tried:

```
current_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'Knowledge Base.html')]")

current_file = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Knowledge Base.html")
```

I have also tried inspecting and copying the xpath of the link. On the webpage, clicking "Knowledge Base.html" brings us to a place where we can upload an html file. I am fairly new to python and HTML as well so I'm wondering if Selenium can't find the link because of the onclick=javascript function. Anyway, any advice is appreciated and let me know if I need to post a bigger chunk of the html or anything.

Comment: What's the url? That's not a proper link I don't think

Comment: I can't post the url because its behind some login pages. I can post a bigger chunk of the html if you think that will help.

Comment: add wait for getting element because,if you redirect to another page it's take time to load and might be element is not present in HTML. `like current_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "text_of_linktag"))) `         
refere :  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits